# Selenium Error - StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-crawler, selenium-chromedriver

Using Selenium, I am attempting to crawl the content of a blog using the code:

```
contents = []
rounds = 0
maxRounds = 100
while(rounds < maxRounds):

    dateList = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('date')
    titleList = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('tit')

    for i in range(len(dateList)):
        if(dateList[i].text == "Today"):
            titleList[i].click()

    contents.append(browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#postContent > p').text)

print(contents)
```

Yet an error appears,

> StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

I have tried letting the program internally and externally wait, but both attempts weren't successful.

Any solutions?

Comment: Without a sample html it is not possible to reproduce your problem, consider adding a [mcve]. Please do note that sometimes, when doing a **minimal** sample of the problem, you may detect the cause of the problem.

Comment: On which line you are getting this exception,

Comment: This will happen when one of your action say click results in a page refresh and you are holding a reference to an element which doesn't exist in dom anymore. You should get the count of titleList at start to know the iteration count and then get dateList and titleList each time inside your loop as your click operation might be refreshing the page.